# How to write query with join that returns RIGHT nulls in JPQL?

Tags: spring, jpql

In a Spring service (Spring Boot 3.0.6), I want to return the following information:

- objects ResolutionList that belong to a certain user, and that have publish=True
- for each ResolutionList, a list of associated Resolution objects that have publish=True.
  Note that this list of Resolutions could be empty, and I'd still want to return the ResolutionList with the empty list.

Is it possible to do this using JPQL?

With standard SQL I would do this easily like:
`SELECT * FROM resolution_list rl left JOIN resolution r on r.resolution_list_id=rl.id and r.publish = true WHERE rl.user_id=?1 and rl.publish=true`

However, can't seem to find a way to translate this JPQL and still be able to return the ResolutionList with the empty list when no Resolutions match the condition.

I've tried `SELECT rl FROM ResolutionList rl LEFT JOIN  Resolution r on r.publish=true WHERE rl.userId=?1 and rl.publish=true`, but the ON clause seems to be ignored.

I have also considered doing this as a nativeQuery, but I have columns with the same name in both tables, so I end up getting "JpaSystemException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [id] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query"

These are the entities I'm using:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "resolution_list")
public class ResolutionList {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "resolution_list_gen", sequenceName = "resolution_list_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "resolution_list_gen")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "resolutionList", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Resolution> resolutions;

    private boolean publish = false;
}

@Entity
public class Resolution {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "resolution_gen", sequenceName = "resolution_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "resolution_gen")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "resolution_list_id", nullable = false)
    private ResolutionList resolutionList;

    private boolean publish = false;
}
```

For additional clarity, if I have this in resolution_list:

| id | userId | publish |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | Y |
| 2 | user1 | Y |
| 3 | user1 | N |
| 4 | user2 | Y |

and this in resolution:

| id | resolution_list_id | publish |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Y |
| 2 | 1 | Y |
| 3 | 1 | N |
| 4 | 2 | N |

the result I expect when launching the query for userId=user1 would be:

| rl.id | rl.userId | rl.publish | r.id | r.publish |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | Y | 1 | Y |
| 1 | user1 | Y | 2 | Y |
| 2 | user1 | Y | NULL | NULL |

So for ResolutionList with id=2, I would expect to end up with a ResolutionList object containing an empty list of Resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Based on plane `SQL` that you provide:

```
SELECT * FROM resolution_list rl left JOIN resolution r on r.resolution_list_id=rl.id and r.publish = true WHERE rl.user_id=?1 and rl.publish=true
```

**UPDATE**

As I said this is how you can obtain wanted result:

Create a [Query Projection](https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-query-projections/)

First of all declare an Interface Projection:

```
public interface ResolutionListDto {

   Integer getResolutionListId();

   Boolean getResolutionListPublish();

   String getUserId();

   Integer getResolutionId();

   Boolean getResolutionPublish();
}
```

Then the query in Repository will have next one body;

```
 @Query(value = """
          SELECT rl.id as resolutionListId,
           rl.publish as resolutionListPublish,
            rl.user_id as userId,
             r.id as resolutionId,
              r.publish as resolutionPublish 
               FROM resolution_list rl
                LEFT JOIN resolution r
                 on r.resolution_list_id = rl.id and r.publish = true
                  WHERE rl.user_id= :userId and rl.publish = true
      """, nativeQuery = true)
  List<ResolutionListDto> getResolutionListDto(@Param("userId") String userId);
```

After invoking next one query the result will be the same as `plane SQL`

[image]

Comment: If I try this it fails unless I remove the ON clause (which is JPQL is not needed). Apart from that, the problem with this solution is that, when there are no Resolutions that match the condition, the ResolutionList doesn't get returned either, which is not what I want.

Comment: Could you provide as update of question  these 2 entity classes ?

Comment: so, the current problem that you have now is in result that you get(not expected result). Can you provide some test data ? I mean some rows from database as update of question, when you also will share expected result. By the way, the main problem was solved(`a way to translate this JPQL`) ?

Comment: I have provided some sample data. But I don't agree the problem was solved, until I have a JPQL that does what I need.

Comment: Yes, I got it, give me some time I will help you as a update of question

Comment: can you check ?  I did an update.

Comment: So, if I'm interpreting your answer correctly, what you are saying is that it's **not possible** to write what I'm looking for as a JPQL query, and the workaround would be to use a native query with a custom query projection. Is that right?

Comment: It is not an workaround in my opinion it is just a way to do query.

Comment: What about the answer did it meet your requirements?