# Spring Boot JPA - UNION, Projection and native query

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, projection

I wonder if it's possible to use projection in native query (native query because I use UNION in my SQL):

Repository:

```
public interface WarehouseRepository extends JpaRepository<Warehouse, Long> {
@Query(value = """
            SELECT MIN(w.valid_from), MAX(w.valid_to)
            FROM (
            SELECT w1.valid_from, w1.valid_to
            FROM warehouse w1
            WHERE ...)
            UNION
            SELECT w2.valid_from, w2.valid_to
            FROM warehouse w2
            LEFT JOIN ...
            WHERE ...
            ) w
            """, nativeQuery = true)
    MyRecord<LocalDate> getSomeValue(@Param long someId,
                              @Param long carId,
                              @Param LocalDateTime dateTime);
```

and my record:

```
public record MyRecord<T>(
        T from,
        T to
) {
    public static <E> Range<E> methodA(E from, E to) {
        ...
    }

    public static <E> Range<E> methodB(E boundary) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: yes of course you could use it, I am going to write and answer related to your case.

Comment: OK, thanks, it's kind of a mix of projection using record + native query

Comment: Update: here you have to use [sql-native-query-result-into-dto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64762080/how-to-map-sql-native-query-result-into-dto-in-spring-jpa-repository) if you want to use ``record` also you could use [Interface Projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77363895/how-to-write-query-with-join-that-returns-right-nulls-in-jpql/77364625#77364625) it is an example of it that I provided an answer to question or last one way in my opinion best one is to create a `view in database`  an then map it to an `Entity` because here you have `UNION` and it is the best approach.

Comment: @AndreiLisa WORKS! Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, for future helps just tag me in a comments )))